# Entity Framework gets progressively slow with extra join added even though SQL generated is fast

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, linq, entity-framework

We have 18 table join which is typical for ERP systems. The join is done via LINQ over Entity Framework.

The join gets progressively slower as more joins are added. The return result set is small(15 records). The LINQ generated query is captured via SQL Profiler and when we run this via Microsoft Management Console it  is very fast : 10ms. When we run it via our C# LINQ-over-EntityFramework it takes 4 seconds.

What i guess is happening:
The time it takes to compile expression tree into SQL is 2 seconds out of total 4 seconds, and another 2 seconds i guess is spent internally to convert SQL result set into actually C# classes. Also it is not connected to initialization of entity framework because we run some queries before and repetitive calls to this join produce same 4 seconds.

Is there a way to speed this up. Otherwise we are considering abandoning Entity Framework for being absolutely inefficient...

Comment: are we talking of a first query of a first instance of a DbContext (that is the first query of the exe)?

Comment: no there were calls to entity framework before. Slowness  is a function of number of joins.

Comment: Statements like "abandoning Entity Framework for being absolutely inefficient..." show a fundamental lack of understanding which technology or approach to use for which problem. Map the result directly instead of letting EF hydrate the entire graph will yield better performance.

Comment: are you in debug or release mode ?

Comment: For what it's worth, I gave up on Entity Framework a long time ago... but not for performance reasons

Comment: Charlie, could you explain in more detail what you mean by " Map the result directly instead of letting EF hydrate the entire graph will yield better performance". We need big join because we want to display it in grid and let user sort and scroll in this grid.

Comment: Gregorie, we tested in both modes, but good idea. Because from my C++ years difference in performance in debug and release mode was 10 times back then. But C# seems a different beast and performance between release and debug is not that striking

Comment: Please post your code Yuriv

Comment: EF figures out the relationships, puts together a complicated query and ask the database for the results. It then materializes and tracks the resulting entities. Teach your database how to do the query, apply appropriate indices, and then use the (stored) procedure to materialize into C#. You are in control of the performance. Understanding your stack is key (disabling EF tracking will also help but you should be aware of the implications of that).

Comment: As it is for reporting, have you tried to put your sql in a view and to use this view with entity farmework ?

Comment: Map only the columns you need for the table to a projection entity.

Comment: Gregorie, yes that is a good workaround to put query into View on sql server. But that will deefy the whole pupose why we decided to use entity framework. We wanted to have database entities which would be properly joined and queried at presentation layer(MVC) but now we end up doing all these presentation level logic on database layer...

Comment: You dont need to take the query out of EF, but using a projection entity, sometimes called a slice, is normal for any application.

Comment: Is there any chance that the model you project the results onto is composed of Collections of any sort (IEnumerable, List, Array etc....)?  I'm having a very similar experience: acceptable query execution time, but slow to convert result set in to object graph.  I've tried mapping the result set onto a minimal view model, (as I believe @CharlieBrown is suggesting), and it helps, but the biggest time sync is projecting onto a view model that has one or more collections in it.  Using AsNoTracking helped me but was not enough to achieve good performance.

Comment: @CharlieBrown, when you describe taking a 'slice', are you essentially suggesting formulating your query via LINQ or fluent API or whatever and capping it off with a call to .Select(myObject => new MySlice{...}).ToList() thus ensuring that you hydrate the bare minimum set of data vs just returning a complete set of entities that the query would yield otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case it helps, I had a nasty performance issue, whereby a simple query that took 1-2 seconds in raw SQL took about 11 seconds via EF.

I went from using...

```
List<GeographicalLocation> geographicalLocations = new SalesTrackerCRMEntities()
  .CreateObjectSet<GeographicalLocation>()
  .Where(g => g.Active)
  .ToList();
```

which took about 11 seconds via EF, to using...

```
var geographicalLocations = getContext().CreateObjectSet<GeographicalLocation>()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(g => g.Active).ToList();
```

which took less than 200 **milliseconds**.

The disadvantage to this is that it won't load related entities, so you have to load them manually afterwards, but it gives such an immense performance boost that it was well worth it (in this case at least).

You would have to assess each case individually to see if the extra speed is worth the extra code.

Comment: this is exactly the problem. We eventually switched to notracking for everything in our project. Entity Framework is just too slow dealing with records retrieved from complex joins. I think something is not optimized how they handle data in memory.

Comment: @Yuriv  Merely using AsNoTracking() boosted your query performance ? I've been in  same situation but AsNoTracking didn't help me.

Comment: yes, disabling tracking helps with performance. Essentially entityframework tries to be smart and tracks every single record it retrieves from db which probably internally takes a lot of time when you have large joins. Please note compiling phase of the joins still slow(first time when u use the join).

Comment: The significant part was the use of AsNoTracking and not the alternative initialization of the ObjectSet, right?

Comment: @BrianSweeney Yes, it was `AsNoTracking` that caused the impressive increase in performance

Answer (score 1):

You correctly identified bottlenecks. 
If you have quite complex queries, I would suggest you to use compiled queries to overcome expression tree to sql query conversion.

You can refer [Compiled Queries in EF from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/hh949853.aspx#4).

Fo second part if EF is using two much time materialize your object graph then I would suggest to use some other means to retrieve data apart from EF.

One option can be [Dapper.NET](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), You can have your concise sql query and you can directly retrieve its result in concrete model objects using Dapper (or any other tiny ORM)

Comment: I up voted just for the Dapper.NET suggestion even though I am not certain you answer is correct.

Comment: 15 joins are 15 joins, no way to be concise in sql or in any ORM, the plumbing must be done

Comment: @tschmit007 it depends on your object model in EF, if you are using complex TPT / TPH / TPC scheme, sometimes query generated by EF tends to be too much complex which you can optimize based on your current situation. Since Yuriv has already mentioned that query works fine which points to problem in materializing response where you can gain using small ORM like Dapper.NET instead of letting EF exhaust entire object graph while deserialization (as correctly suggested by TheCatWhisper)

Comment: Sameer,i think you are the closest to the root of our problem. When you say " letting EF exhaust entire object graph ". What does that actually mean. Do you mean in a join Entity Framework internally does create EF classes for each intermediate join and that is where the time is spent?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your query takes so long to generate becuase you are treating Entity Framework like it is a SQL Query, which is not correct. You have many joins and akward calls in your linq syntax. Generally, your syntax should be similar to the following fictitious modeling query:

```
var result = (from appointment in appointments
              from operation in appointment.Operations
              where appointment.Id == 12
              select new Model {
                 Id = appointment.Id,
                 Name = appointment.Name,
                 // etc, etc
              }).ToList();
```

There is no use of joins above, the navigation property between Appointment and Operations takes care of the neccessary plumbing. Remember, this is an ORM, there is no concept of a join, only a concept of relationships.

The call to `Distinct` at the end, also indicates the structure of the db schema may be problematic if it returns too many duplicate results.

If after refactoring the entity model and correctly constructing the query still leaves with underperformance, it is advisable to use a stored procedure and map the result with EF's built in methods for doing so.

Comment: we cannot use ToList because that would convert thousands of records to in memory objects. we want to use IQuaryable in grids. This is clearly a poor suggestion

Comment: IQueryable should never be used in a grid. The Tolist() will only create what you select.

Comment: Telerik thinks differently: http://www.telerik.com/forums/paging-sorting-and-filtering-with-iqueryable-datasource

Comment: @Yuriv They are talking about using an IQueryable datasource. List<T> is an IQueryable datasource, so binding List<T> will work just fine. You do not want the IQueryable from EF bound to it directly, for more reasons that I could cover in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what is going wrong here without seeing how you are using linq, but I suspect this will fix your problem:

```
var myResult = dataContext.table.Where(x == "Your joins and otherstuff").ToList();
//after converting it to a list use it how you need, but not before.
```

If this does not help please post your code.

Comment: you asked me for the actual code, i give it here but really it doesn't matter because as i said earlier we have an issue of each join decreasing performance even on small returned dataset, so it is not a question of optimizing specific joins:

Comment: With linq, it doesn't necessarily work like a sql query does, sometimes it can do some weird stuff. The problem might not be the joins, but how you are using the returned result set

Comment: here how i measure time and use result: long tmp = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks;
var res2 = tasks.FirstOrDefault();
long sp = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks-tmp;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are probably passing it to a data source that is running all sorts of additional queries based on you open result set.

Try this instead:

```
IEnumerable<SigmaTEK.Web.Models.SchedulerGridModel> tasks = (from appointment in _appointmentRep.Value.Get().Where(a => (a.Start < DbContext.MaxTime && DbContext.MinTime < a.Expiration))
                                                                    join timeApplink in _timelineAppointmentLink.Value.Get().Where(a => a.AppointmentId != Guid.Empty)
                                                                    on appointment.Id equals timeApplink.AppointmentId
                                                                    join timeline in timelineRep.Value.Get().Where(i => timelines.Contains(i.Id))
                                                                    on timeApplink.TimelineId equals timeline.Id
                                                                    join repeater in _appointmentRepeaterRep.Value.Get().Where(repeater => (repeater.Start < DbContext.MaxTime && DbContext.MinTime < repeater.Expiration))
                                                                    on appointment.Id equals repeater.Appointment
                                                                    into repeaters

                                                                    from repeater in repeaters.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                    join aInstance in _appointmentInstanceRep.Value.Get()
                                                                    on appointment.Id equals aInstance.Appointment
                                                                    into instances

                                                                    from instance in instances.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                    join opRes in opResRep.Get()
                                                                    on instance.ResourceOwner equals opRes.Id
                                                                    into opResources

                                                                    from op in opResources.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                    join itemResource in _opDocItemResourcelinkRep.Value.Get()
                                                                    on op.Id equals itemResource.Resource
                                                                    into itemsResources

                                                                    from itemresource in itemsResources.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                    join opDocItem in opDocItemRep.Get()
                                                                    on itemresource.OpDocItem equals opDocItem.Id
                                                                    into opDocItems

                                                                    from opdocitem in opDocItems.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                    join opDocSection in opDocOpSecRep.Get()
                                                                    on opdocitem.SectionId equals opDocSection.Id
                                                                    into sections

                                                                    from section in sections.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                    join opDoc in opDocRep.Get()
                                                                    on section.InternalOperationalDocument equals opDoc.Id
                                                                    into opdocs

                                                                    from opdocitem2 in opDocItems.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                    join opDocItemLink in opDocItemStrRep.Get()
                                                                    on opdocitem2.Id equals opDocItemLink.Parent
                                                                    into opDocItemLinks

                                                                    from link in opDocItemLinks.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                    join finItem in finItemsRep.Get()
                                                                    on link.Child equals finItem.Id
                                                                    into temp1

                                                                    from rd1 in temp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                    join sec in finSectionRep.Get()
                                                                    on rd1.SectionId equals sec.Id
                                                                    into opdocsections

                                                                    from finopdocsec in opdocsections.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                    join finopdoc in opDocRep.Get().Where(i => i.DocumentType == "Quote")
                                                                     on finopdocsec.InternalOperationalDocument equals finopdoc.Id
                                                                     into finOpdocs

                                                                    from finOpDoc in finOpdocs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                    join entry in entryRep.Get()
                                                                    on rd1.Transaction equals entry.Transaction
                                                                    into entries

                                                                    from entry2 in entries.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                    join resproduct in resprosductRep.Get()
                                                                     on entry2.Id equals resproduct.Entry
                                                                     into resproductlinks

                                                                    from resprlink in resproductlinks.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                    join res in resRep.Get()
                                                                    on resprlink.Resource equals res.Id
                                                                    into rootResource

                                                                    from finopdoc in finOpdocs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                    join rel in orgDocIndRep.Get().Where(i => (i.Relationship == "OrderedBy"))
                                                                    on finopdoc.Id equals rel.OperationalDocument
                                                                    into orgDocIndLinks

                                                                    from orgopdoclink in orgDocIndLinks.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                    join org in orgRep.Get()
                                                                    on orgopdoclink.Organization equals org.Id
                                                                    into toorgs

                                                                    from opdoc in opdocs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                    from rootresource in rootResource.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                    from toorg in toorgs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                    select new SigmaTEK.Web.Models.SchedulerGridModel()
                                                                    {

                                                                        Id = appointment.Id,
                                                                        Description = appointment.Description,
                                                                        End = appointment.Expiration,
                                                                        Start = appointment.Start,
                                                                        OperationDisplayId = op.DisplayId,
                                                                        OperationName = op.Name,
                                                                        AppContextId = _appContext.Id,
                                                                        TimelineId = timeline.Id,
                                                                        AssemblyDisplayId = rootresource.DisplayId,
                                                                        //Duration = SigmaTEK.Models.App.Utils.StringHelpers.TimeSpanToString((appointment.Expiration - appointment.Start)),
                                                                        WorkOrder = opdoc.DisplayId,
                                                                        Organization = toorg.Name
                                                                    }).Distinct().ToList();

//In your UI
MyGrid.DataSource = tasks;
MyGrid.DataBind();
```

//Do not use an ObjectDataSource! It makes too many extra calls

Comment: well, that ToList() call will take 4 seconds... So this code not going to change anything. Because it is when you call ToList the query will be compiled and executed. And that is precisely where our performance bottleneck is.

Comment: Well it seems to me that will only be a problem on the first run. However, another solution is to write a stored procedure than create an entity from the stored procedure.

Comment: But think about your own suggestion we now start doing all these stored procedures, SQL Views just to please entity framework so it can run faster. What i am looking for is maybe somebody knows how to hint entity framework how to speedup conversion of expression tree into query and hint EF to speedup convertion of sql resultset back into C# classes when query was executed.

Comment: Maybe Entity Framework is not the right solution for you? Perhaps Dapper.NET is more appropriate?

Comment: maybe... But i still hope maybe somebody suggests key optimization technique for entity framework since we use it already and switching to something else is an expensive undertaking

Comment: This is a clear cut use case for a stored procedure. It's not about pleasing entity framework, its about using the correct technology for the task. EF does not alleviate the developer from having to never used sprocs.

Comment: Charlie you seem to be an experienced developer. So you should understand that there is absolutely no reason why conversion of 18 table types into SQL statement should take 2 seconds on i7 processor. There is something else happening under the hood. And that where i need help.

Comment: Start with refactoring your model. You should not need the DefaultIfEmpty() or the joins. Your models should have navigation properties which EF will use to help create the query.